# how to use jsfiddle code in my angularjs application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, dynamic-tables

I have to use this [jsfiddle code](http://www.jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/rnnb32rm/2/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=rnnb32rm)  in my application, as I am going to enter all the code in one page company.html, it shows me only this [image: output]instead of this[image: output]. Could anybody please explain me why is this problem occuring, i think the problem is with this

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.choices = [{id: 'choice1'}, {id: 'choice2'}];

$scope.addNewChoice = function() {
var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
$scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});
};

$scope.removeChoice = function() {
var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
$scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
};

});
```

regarding to module name or kind of that.
I am getting this error in browser console:
[image]

Comment: did you import angularjs?

Comment: Yes, I'm working on an AngularJS application, just this page is making me face this problem. Also my application module('bootstrapApp')

Comment: Whenever you see `{{ }}` on the page in an AngularJs app, it means that you encountered some error which will be listed in the browser console.  Please [edit] your question and provide that error message.

Comment: Did you mean browser console? #Claies

Comment: Make sure you use angular1.2.1 for this code. That's what the author has used.

Comment: I added the browser console error message, please check out. @Claies

Comment: well, the error says "The controller with the name 'MainCtrl' is not registered", which either means that your scripts are not loading in the correct order or your `ng-app` in your HTML isn't set to the correct module name.  In this case, posting the code **you wrote** instead of the code you tried to **copy from** is necessary to understand the differences.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error because of your `Immediately Invoked Function Expression`. you have to change it like below :

```js
/* ------------------------------------------------------- 

* Filename:     Adding Form Fields Dynamically
* Website:      http://www.shanidkv.com
* Description:  Shanidkv AngularJS blog
* Author:       Muhammed Shanid shanidkannur@gmail.com

---------------------------------------------------------*/

var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.choices = [{
    id: 'choice1'
  }, {
    id: 'choice2'
  }];

  $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
    $scope.choices.push({
      'id': 'choice' + newItemNo
    });
  };

  $scope.removeChoice = function() {
    var lastItem = $scope.choices.length - 1;
    $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
  };

})(angularjs-starter);
```

```css
fieldset {
  background: #FCFCFC;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
}

.addfields {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#choicesDisplay {
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgb(227, 250, 227);
  border: 1px solid rgb(171, 239, 171);
  color: rgb(9, 56, 9);
}

.remove {
  background: #C76868;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 21px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 9px;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 100%;
}

input[type="text"],
select {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <fieldset data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
    <select>
         <option>Mobile</option>
         <option>Office</option>
         <option>Home</option>
      </select>
    <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="" placeholder="Enter mobile number">
    <button class="remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>
  </fieldset>
  <button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add fields</button>

  <div id="choicesDisplay" style="visibility:hidden;">
  </div>
</div>
```

> If you Need the choices display to come up just let me know. Will add
>   that!  Just copy the code and you are good to go. Make sure the CSS
>   part is inside your style tag while Angular inside your Script tag.

Happy Coding :)